# not bool does not work but bool != True works

Tags: python, pandas, boolean

I am trying to find the list of unique colours from the CSV downloaded from https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Environment/2018-Central-Park-Squirrel-Census-Squirrel-Data/vfnx-vebw

The following **does not** work:

```
data = pandas.read_csv("2018_Central_Park_Squirrel_Census_-_Squirrel_Data.csv")

fur_color_col = data["Primary Fur Color"]
print(data[not pandas.isna(data["Primary Fur Color"])]["Primary Fur Color"].unique())
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/arvind.avinash/PycharmProjects/AdHoc/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(data[not pandas.isna(data["Primary Fur Color"])]["Primary Fur Color"].unique())
  File "/Users/arvind.avinash/PycharmProjects/AdHoc/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1537, in __nonzero__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

The following **works**:

```
data = pandas.read_csv("2018_Central_Park_Squirrel_Census_-_Squirrel_Data.csv")

fur_color_col = data["Primary Fur Color"]
print(data[pandas.isna(data["Primary Fur Color"]) != True]["Primary Fur Color"].unique())
```

and outputs:

```
['Gray' 'Cinnamon' 'Black']
```

Why does `not bool` not work while `bool != True` does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `non` for arrays (in pandas or numpy) is operator `~`, so need:

```
print(data[~pandas.isna(data["Primary Fur Color"])]["Primary Fur Color"].unique())
```

For compare in arrays (in pandas or numpy) are used same operators like in pure python, so `!= True` working well.

---

Or is possible use [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html):

```
print(data.loc[data["Primary Fur Color"].notna(), "Primary Fur Color"].unique())
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason that `not` does not work, is that it is [defined by the language spec](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) to return a single boolean value, which does not make much sense with a Pandas series.

> The operator not yields True if its argument is false, False otherwise.

The `!=` operator has no such limitations, which means that Pandas is free to define it as an element-by-element comparison.